# Received letter from police for being drunk and riding bicycle in Germany

Tags: germany, legal, bicycles, alcohol, fines

I was caught being drunk while riding a bicycle and the letter states that it is a criminal offence. The letter mentioned a couple of options that I can follow such as 1. Accepting the crime, 2. Express yourself in a letter, 3. Pay fine, 4. Go to a lawyer, etc.
My position is: I was drunk true, but I was not going to ride the bicycle home. It was 2 o'clock in the morning and I was with two guys, who had the bicycle. The bicycles were parked in front of a church and since there was no one on the streets, I was just trying one bicycle and could have gone 50-60 meter in the pavement when the police caught me.

I understand I broke a law. I am foreigner, I didn't know this law. This drunk bicycling can lead to a criminal offence, I did not realise that. I am very embarrassed about my actions.

Now I want to express my self in a letter. Since the law is not my domain, I would like to get some help, if anyone can help me out or give me some hints on how I should draft my letter.
And, if possible also let me know how much fine I have to pay. Its been only one month since I am working.

Thanks

Comment: A letter will not help. Either accept the fine or find a Lawyer.

Comment: Yes, I am ready to pay the fine. Could you please tell me how much will be the amount.

Comment: This will be decided by the court and will depend on the exact circumstances. But my point is, a letter will not make anything better. In reality, you just have the option to accept the fine or get a lawyer.

Comment: This is probably better suited for [law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I can't say exactly what your fine will be, but based on several articles I ran across while casually looking for info, it appears that it'll probably be several hundred euros.  Did they measure your blood alcohol content?  Did they say how much it was?

Comment: The amount of your fine will depend on the circumstances. Did you endanger other people or cause an accident? Are you a repeating offender? Did you break other rules while cycling drunk (e.g. cycling on the sidewalk)? These and some other factors will be considered.

Comment: @jcaron if posted on Law, this question would risk being closed as a request for legal advice.  It would stand a better chance if rephrased in hypothetical terms.  I don't imagine it would find a better answer there than it has received here, however.

Comment: Officer: You were riding your bicycle while drunk. You: No it wasn't my bicycle, it was one  I stole from outside a church. Officer:...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not a travel question. The OP is asking for legal advice. He should ask on [law.se], and consider hiring a lawyer.

Comment: As I understand it, they are **offering summary judgement** of the case and inform you of your legal options, which include *accepting the fine* or *making a statement* or *going to court with a lawyer* or *going to court without a lawyer*. The system is set up so that the summary judgement is more lenient than what a judge *might* set out, so if you are guilty and plan to admit it you should accept the summary fine, without any statement on details. Get someone you trust with your personal details to translate the letter for you; you can retain a lawyer for just that, without going to court.

Comment: (continued) It might also be a good idea to talk to a lawyer before answering the letter to find out how a driving-under-the-influence record affects your future and if it counts as a criminal conviction. Germany won't kick you out over a single DUI, but you might have to answer "have you ever been convicted of a crime" e.g. on visa applications.

Comment: @o.m. thanks for the comment. This is exactly what I am going to do. I have already taken an appointment with a lawyer. After the consultation, I will submit the form.

Answer (score 16):

If you in Germany ride a bicycle under influence of alcohol and your blood alcohol content is above 0.16% *or* the police deem you incapable of riding the bicycle without endangering others, the consequences are basically the same as if you had been driving a motorized vehicle. It is of no relevance that you were only riding 50-60m or that it was not your bicycle.

Expressing yourself in a letter will potentially only make matters worse, since you might admit to something the police is not yet aware of. You can not expect such a letter to have any significance for your defence.

If the accusations against you are factually correct and there are no obvious mitigating circumstances, you might be better admitting the crime and face the penalty. Otherwise, you should hire a lawyer for your defence. Unless you are entitled to a free lawyer, you must however consider that you have to pay the lawyer on top of any penalty you will get from the court.

As you pointed out in a comment, your BAC was measured to 0.166% and therefore above the absolute 0.16% limit. The charges against you are therefore not based on a subjective assesement of your capability to operate a bicycle. With a BAC that high, you must in addition to a fine also expect that your driver's license (or right to drive in Germany, in case you have a foreign license) will be revoked. If you really depend on your driver's license, e.g. to perform your occupation, the court have the option to give you some leeway and let you keep your license. In this case, you may also be better off hiring a lawyer to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking to state that I accept the charges and ready to pay the fine. And, along with that, I will also request the court/police give a sympathetic look on this matter and if possible relieve me from the penalty. Since I just recently started working. I am very shaky from the finance point of view. Is it that will be a good idea?

Comment: @Sanjudas This would also depend on how much was found in the alcohol test. Fines can be up to one month pay (after taxes) and could effect your drivers licence if you have one. If you are sure the police understood the situation correctly (just trying out the bike), then **no** letter should be written.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Alcohol content was 1.66 promile. 1.66 is the threshold got to know. I am not sure that police understood my situation that I am just trying out one bike. When I said that it was not my bike, I was trying out for a few meters, they said it does not matter if you ride for 1 meter also (drunk) then also it is an offence.

Comment: @Sanjudas The fine (amount of days, based on your earnings) will probably be much lower than 30, since it will be based on the situation.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: @Sanjudas Why do you (still?) think that the police didn't understand the situation correctly? I can say it once again: It is of no relevance that you were only riding 50-60m or that it was not your bicycle.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I understand what you are saying. I did not understand the letter much. In the letter, it was mentioned that I am charged with "infolge Alkohol (§316 StGB)" and in accordance with § 163a Abs. 1 Satz 3 Strafprozeßordnung, I am given the change to explain myself.

Comment: @Sanjudas Do you have a driver's license on which you rely upon, e.g. to do your work? With a BAC above 0.16%, you must also expect that your driver's license will be revoked. If you depend upon it for your own sustenance, you may also consider hiring a lawyer to help you keep it.

Comment: @Sanjudas Please let us know how things unfold

Comment: In addition to losing your drivers licence, if you haven't got one yet, this will be taken into account if you every apply to get one in Germany. They have a very long memory, and the licence penalty will be enforced once you have one. Growing up in a village in Germany, I know a few people who got caught at 17 riding a bike home very drunk and they all had to wait much later than their 18th birthday to be allowed to drive.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks for the comment. I have filled up the form and sent it to the police yesterday. I am very regretful for this incident, nothing of this sort ever happened in my life earlier. Now, there will be a criminal history in my record. Nonetheless, I am not much concern about driving license because I don't drive anyway. My concern is: I have just started my career, it's been only one month that I am working. I just hope that there will not be any negative consequences in my resident permit because of this case!!

Comment: @Sanjudas I've [asked the city of Hannover on Twitter](https://twitter.com/hannover/status/1295365940285243399) about your residence permit (well actually I asked about a _Niederlassungserlaubnis_, I didn't know what you have). They said that their local Ausländerbehörde says this incident will not have a negative effect if you already have one. They didn't say if it would make it harder getting one. IIRC the thing I asked for is a settlement permit, so this might not be entirely accurate.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks a lot for the comment. My earlier nervousness has gone now. I'll what happens.