# Future consequences related to a charge of criminal offence: Drinking and riding bicycle in Germany

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, schengen-visas, finland, criminal-records

I am a non-EU person and a few months earlier, I was accused of a criminal offence of drink and riding a bicycle (the event was only for 2-3 minutes, no one hurt, police caught me immediately). After some days of this charge, I have received a letter stating: if I agree to pay a fine all the legal proceeding against me will be discontinued without any further notification to me. And, there will be neither an entry in the federal central register nor in the registry of fitness to drive. I will be deemed to have no criminal record. I have fulfilled the obligations in a timely fashion.

At present, I am searching for a job and this week I have received a job offer from Finland. So to proceed further, I need to apply for a Finnish visa. In the visa form, there is a section of criminal history and certain questions were asked, for example,

1. Have you ever been convicted of an offence and sentenced to punishment?
2. Do you consent to the Finnish migration authorities obtaining a criminal record extract or similar report from foreign authorities?

In my case, I could not able to make up my mind. What should I write in the form? Should I mentioned about the incident of drink and riding a bicycle or not (although in the letter it was mentioned that if I pay the fine then there will be no record against me)?

I will be grateful if anyone can give some information on this.

Comment: I don't understand what's unclear about the question. Does the visa application form ask if you have been convicted of a crime or does it ask if you have been convicted of a crime resulting in a record in a registry of convictions?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo the visa form particularly ask the question that : Have you ever been convicted of an offence and sentenced to punishment? I am thinking: is it okay if I write no. Because the letter that I receive it was mentioned that if I pay the fine then there will be no criminal record against my name. This is my doubt. Should I write yes or no? My logic is if there is no criminal record then I have never been convicted of an offence.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo it was also mentioned that if I pay the fine then the procedure against me will be discontinued.

Comment: Please use an alias instead of using your original name!!! You certainly do not want this article to pop up in google if someone searches your name along with keywords such as Germany/Finland

Comment: Related question by same author: [Received letter from police for being drunk and riding bicycle in Germany (closed)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158705/20141)

Comment: @MaxPayne Good advice in general, but if the worst thing about Aragorn that one could find with a google search is that he was once caught riding a bicycle while drunk (and promptly settled the matter with the authorities), he's pretty much fine. One can dig much more dirt on an average person with a facebook account.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev his/her stack profile has his/her full name

Comment: @spikey_richie I figured they don't want it mentioned here after all, and I respect that, so I used "Aragorn".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Received letter from police for being drunk and riding bicycle in Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158705/received-letter-from-police-for-being-drunk-and-riding-bicycle-in-germany)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Fact 1: You haven’t been convicted. Fact 2: You have been fined. Fact 3: You have committed an offence (that’s what you told us). Fact 4: There is no record in Germany that you were even accused of an offence. Fact 5: You have never been charged of an offence.

You should answer the exact questions that you were asked truthfully. The truthful answer to question 1 is “no”. You took the offer to get rid of the matter by paying a fine, therefore no charge, no conviction, no punishment, no record. Good move on your side.

The second question: If you don’t agree, I bet you won’t get a visa. On the other hand, there will be no record of the matter in Germany so a search will turn up nothing.

(Other countries may ask different questions, like “were you ever charged...” and you would have to answer “yes” if you were charged even if you were later proven innocent. In such a situation lying will most likely give you more trouble than saying the truth. But in your case: You were not charged. ).

Comment: Why do you say OP was not charged? OP themselves said, "After some days of this *charge*...the legal proceeding against me will be discontinued..." So there was a legal proceeding underway that OP understood as a charge.

Comment: @nanoman I don't know if German and English law are different, but under English law the OP would have been *accused* of the offence, but not *charged* with it. If the OP admits the offence and pays the fixed penalty by the stated time, no *charges* are ever brought. If the OP does not pay, or   wants to dispute the facts of the situation, then a charge will be brought resulting in a court case, and the charge will be formally recorded. (Of course if the OP is then found guilty, the total cost of the fine and court costs will be much higher than the fixed penalty).

Comment: Most of this answer is wrong. In Germany, accepting a Strafbefehl, as OP obviously has done, carries the same consequences and is equivalent to actually having been sentenced by a court.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo This answer simply addresses the question as stated. See e.g. "I will be deemed to have no criminal record.", "all the legal proceeding against me will be discontinued". Based on that, this answer is correct. Now, OP may well be *wrong* to have made those assumptions, but that would be a question (and answer) for law stackexchange. The question more generally can be read as "If I accepted a fine which results in me having no conviction, how should I answer the following question?".

Comment: @JBentley  "If I accepted a fine which results in me having no conviction, how should I answer the following question?" is not what OP asked and definitely not relevant to what has happened. What OP obviously has done is accepting a Strafbefehl, which in layman's terms is more or less a question like "do you accept a conviction with the following penalty without taking the case to court?". Accepting a Strafbefehl has in Germany the same effect as being sentenced to an enforceable conviction from a court.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: 
Out of curiousity, is a speeding ticket also a Strafbehehl (I suspect it is, given the above)? I'm having a hard time reporting a speeding ticket as "...everr been convicted of an offence and sentenced to punishment...". If only because I get around 4 to 5 of them a year (albeit in The Netherlands), which, after 30 years of driving, would pretty much make me the most wanted man in Europe.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt No. In Germany, a law violation is categorized as an Ordnungswidrigkeit, Vergehen or Verbrechen in rising severity. Drunk driving is a Vergehen and may be sanctioned with a Strafbefehl, while speeding is 'just' an Ordnungswidrigkeit. Be aware though, that speeding is seen seriously enough in many European countries. In Norway it is not too difficult to end up in jail for speeding and Finland has been handing out 6-digit (in Euros) fines to people going too fast. Is that enough for you to make 'sentenced to punishment' seem like an appropriate description?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Your criticism is valid, but I think it could also be a "Verfahrenseinstellung gegen Geldauflage" (§ 153a StPO), which is not equivalent to a conviction. In that case, OP could safely answer his first question with "no". I'm not sure if "You were not charged" is true in this case. A dropped charge might be different from no charge.

Comment: @Stefan Based on OP's previous question he was caught riding a bicycle with a blood alcohol content of 0.166%. I can't really imagine that § 153a StPO is relevant in this case. But as I already stated in another comment: To understand and interpret the question, it is probably of much more interest how Finnish authorities would 'grade' the act and/or the consequences and not so relevant to discuss the nuances and labelling of the different German criminal sanctions.

Comment: The accusation was according to § 316 Abs. 1 and 2 StGB. But the Staatsanwaltschaft office intended to refrain from filing charges in accordance with section § 153a Abs. 1 StPO, provided I fulfil the mentioned condition. I have fulfilled the obligations, and today, I went to Staatsanwaltschaft office to double-check the matter. They gave me a letter stating the proceeding is discontinued as per § 153a Abs. 1 StPO. So, I believe, now I can write "no" as an answer to the above question with full confidence.

Comment: I sincerely like to thanks all the people who made their valuable comments and discussed the matter at great length. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

**Depends on the fine print.**

German law has something called a **Strafbefehl**, a non-negotiable, court-approved offer of a plea bargain. One can take it or request a full court case. The Strafbefehl is only possible for a misdemeanor, and differences between a crime and a misdemeanor are problematic when it comes to translations.

It could also be a simple fine for a public order offense, which is not a crime.

Comment: The distinction between offenses and crimes in German law is important.

Comment: It is probably more relevant how Finnish authorities see the situation. If whatever happened in Germany falls into what Finnish law considers to be 'convicted of an offence', the categorization in Germany may not be relevant at all.

Comment: Finland is not going to have a list of countries and offences in them to reinterpret them according to Finnish law. So it gets blurry when the legal system of another country is very different from the Finnish legal system. Whether or not the punishment is recorded in your criminal record is likely a good rule-of-thumb but if you want absolute certainty, then a lawyer, preferably one that understands both Finnish immigration law and German law, is likely your only option.

Comment: In Finland it is illegal to drink and drive a bicycle but there is no punishment because there is no limit for blood alcohol in this case.

Answer (score -1):

OK. Literal interpretation.
You can truthfully answer no even if you do not intend to pay the fine. You have not been convicted.

But... if you don't pay the fine and you are ever asked again, such as upon entry, you might have to answer yes.
So yeah, answer quickly and pay the fine.